# flume with multiple Avro schemas

Tags: schema, flume, avro, serialization

I am using Flume to combine small Avro files (each containing a couple of Avro events) into larger files to be stored in HDFS. I am using Spool source and HDFS sink, with Avro Serializer. My Spool directory contains files with 3 different schemas. Is it possible to configure Flume in such a way that it combines Avro files with each different schema into different sink files ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes in fact it is. What actually flume actually does is to wrap your Avro objects into another Avro container object of type Event, which consists of a headers and a body. That body actually contains your Avro objects.

In order to have those files spooled to different directories in hdfs, you will have to set headers, which you can reference in your path, e.g.:

```
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://namenode/%{avro_type}/
```

`avro_type` being the name of the header you set.

In order to set that header, you need to use an interceptor. An interceptor is a custom class which implements `org.apache.flume.interceptor.Interceptor`. In the  `public Event intercept(Event event)` method, you will have determine the type of the avro object and call `event.getHeaders().put("avro_type", <something>);`

That's basically it.

Comment: Thanks for your remark Erik; this was infact for me an eye opener; fact that the body contains the avro object. Another thing to mention is if you specific AVRO_EVENT as the serializer in the hdfs sink then it will actually write the whole (outer) avro object while actually you probably only want the inner avro object. This can be accomplished by setting the serializer to org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AvroEventSerializer$Builder which takes the schema from either the LITERAL or from an uri; see the flume code basically...

Comment: that's correct, the default serialier will just write Flume's avro format